# Regex match a substring if that substring is not preceded by a specific string and ignore the whole string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing, nlp

Trying a few things with negative and positive look-behind, can't really get exactly what I want. Went through this SO question as well: [Regex match a substring if that substring is not preceded by a specific string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071699/regex-match-a-substring-if-that-substring-is-not-preceded-by-a-specific-string)

What I want is just a "yes this entire string should be considered" and a "no, ignore this entire string", because of these substring matches. The post above will help me match the substring, but if the negative words precede the substring, it's still a match, you can see my tests here: https://regex101.com/r/aqn1gO/2

What I'm trying to do is have a regex match for the substring `i need`, but ignore cases where it's not a request, but more a question. The examples are:

1. i need you to do this
2. hey i need this by tomorrow
3. hey do i need this in the deliverable?
4. hey should i need to do this?
5. how are you doing today?

Where `1.` and `2.` should match, but `3.`, `4.`, and `5.` should not, even though there's an `i need` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be then to negate those with `do` or `should` followed by any chars and a must positive lookahead with `i need`:

```
^(?=.*i need.*)(?!.*should.*i need.*|.*do.*i need.*).*$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BIGF3j/1)

Comment: Demo 2 is close but I require the substring `i\s+need` to be present in the string to take action, except for when it is preceded by specific keywords like `(do|should)` (this list might grow). So any other string like "hey how's it going today?" should not trigger a match. I've updated the question with this example to make it more clear.